# Массив в PHP

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if($_POST['reset']=="Очистить")
{
$_POST['min']='';
$_POST['max']='';
$_POST['ar']='';
$_POST['status']='';
}
if($_POST[status]=="1" ){
    $rb1="checked";$rb2="";
} else if($_POST[status]=="2" ){
    $rb1="";$rb2="checked";
}
echo <<<CODE
<form method ="POST">
<table>
     <tr><td><p> Введите значение длины массива</p></td></tr>
     <tr><td><input name='ar' size='12' type='text' value="{$_POST['ar']}"></td></tr>
     <tr><td><p>Введите случайное минимальное число</p></td></tr>
     <tr><td><input name='min' size='12' type='text' value="{$_POST['min']}"></td></tr>
     <tr><td> Введите случайное максимальное число </td></tr>
     <tr><td><input name='max' size='12' type='text' value="{$_POST['max']}"></td></tr>
     <tr><td> $str </td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type='radio' name='status' value='1' $rb1> по возрастанию </td></tr>
<tr><td> <input type='radio' name='status' value='2' $rb2>по убыванию </td></tr>
          <tr><td><input type='submit' name='1' value='OK'>
     <input type='submit' name='reset' value='Очистить'></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
CODE;
if ($_POST ['1']=='OK' && $_POST['status']== ""){
echo "вид не выбран! </br>";
}
if ($_POST ['1']=='OK' && $_POST['ar']== ""){
echo "длина массива не введена! </br>";
}
if ($_POST ['1']=='OK' && $_POST['min']== ""){
echo "минимальное число не введено! </br>";
}
if ($_POST ['1']=='OK' && $_POST['max']== ""){
echo "максимальное число не введено! </br>";
}
if($_POST['1']=="OK"){
if ($_POST['ar'] != "" && $_POST['min'] != "" && 
$_POST['max'] != "" && $_POST['status']!="") {
for($i=0;$i<$_POST['ar'];$i++) {
$new_ar[$i] = $mas [$i]=rand($_POST['min'],$_POST['max']);
}
if($rb1){
sort($new_ar);
} else {
rsort($new_ar);
}
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Массив</td> <td>Отсортированный массив</td>";
echo "</tr>";
for($i=0;$i<$_POST['ar'];$i++) { 
echo "<tr> <td>".$mas [$i]."</td><td>".$new_ar[$i]."</td></tr>";
} 
echo"</table>";
}
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

подскажите пожалуйста как в данном коде сделать чтоб было так

например:

введите минимальное число
1

---

введите максимальное число
10

---

по возрастанию

и результат

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

и подскажите как вместо sort сделать sortmass

Comment: Вот вам примерный алгоритм:
1. Удалить к чёрту то, что там написано
2. Написать заново, но разделить вывод и формирование массива

Не понимаю тех, кто будет это читать.

Comment: да уж если сильно умный то помог бы а не писал ересть

Comment: @wolf123 а он все правильно сказал, код страшный, вопрос туманный, в php нет функции `sortmass`. Скорее всего, задача из универа и вы не ходили на пары либо задача для себя и вам лень читать книги.

Comment: sortmass нету я знаю меня преподаватель попросил её встроить а как её встроить если она не стандартная??????

Comment: в универ я ходил просто не понимаю как вставить в код sortmass а не sort!

Comment: и ниче мне не лень просто не понимаю пока что как сделать то что спросил

Comment: и ещё вопрос в чем мой код страшный??????7

Comment: Вопрос нормально сформируйте, я ничего не понял!

Comment: function sortmax($arg) {}

Answer (score 2):

sortmass нужно сделать самому вот так

```
function sortmass($array) {
  // здесь код для сортировки массива
}
```

А вообще правильно вам сказали - если лень читать и учить ВАМ, то уж тем более это лень нам делать за вас :) Уважайте окружающих и потрудитесь нормально задать вопрос и дать нормальный код а не вываливать людям свой HTML

Answer (score 1):

Частенько приходится сортировать многомерный массив...

Вот например как сортируется ассоциативный массив $array по элементу "date".

```
usort($array, create_function('$a, $b', 'if ($a["date"] == $b["date"]) return 0; return ($a["date"] < $b["date"]) ? 1 : -1;'));
```

`1 : -1` - означает убывание, если нужно возрастание то: `-1 : 1`